# SolrCloud Base ConfigSet does not exist: sitecore_content_config

Tags: solr, container, sitecore-managed-cloud

I run Sitecore 10.2 with SXA in containers and I deleted all my SOLR data, SOLR Cloud have 0 collections and only a default configset in ZooKeeper.

The solr-init containers give the following error on start:

```
Downloading '_default' SOLR config set

Downloading 'contractions_ca.txt' file

.....

Invoke-RestMethod : 

  

    org.apache.solr.common.SolrException

    org.apache.solr.common.SolrException

  

  Base ConfigSet does not exist: sitecore_content_config

  400

At C:\Copy-SolrConfig.ps1:15 char:9

+ $null = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $solrPostConfigUrl -Credential (Get-So ...

+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt 

   pWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe 

   ll.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Downloading 'stopwords_no.txt' file

....

Tranformation managed-schema

Tranformation solrconfig.xml

SolrCollectionsToDeploy exists, skipping base configset creation.

Creating 'sitecore_sxa_master_index_config' SOLR config set based on sitecore_content_config
```

No indexes are created. How to fix this?
I'm using the sitecore-xp0-solr-init image and sitecore-sxa-xp1-assets

Answer (score 0):

You get this Base `ConfigSet does not exist: sitecore_content_config` error when you run the `start.ps1` in the `solr-init` container when you have set a value in the **SOLR_COLLECTIONS_TO_DEPLOY** parameter and have not already the Sitecore base config.

The error also says it is about creating the `sitecore_sxa_master_index_config`, likely you have set `SOLR_COLLECTIONS_TO_DEPLOY: sxa`
leave the `SOLR_COLLECTIONS_TO_DEPLOY` parameter empty, then the Base Config Set will deploy first before creating the indexes.

Take a look at your `docker-compose.yml`, `docker-compose.override.yml` e.t.c or, in the case of Sitecore Managed Cloud See
the application repo, `roles/sitecore-xp/templates/searchstax-solr-init-sxa-spe.yaml`
and adjust or set an empty value in the `SOLR_COLLECTIONS_TO_DEPLOY` parameter.